# What would be an appropriate term for "silent movies"?

Tags: names, obscure-terms

All of us know what a silient movie is. but as far as I reasearched, i found that "Silent Movies" is not a suitable term because they are often accompanied by music.

so, my question is, what could be an appropriate name for "silent movies"?

Comment: The correct / appropriate name is 'silent movies' or 'silent films' (largely UK). Claiming it is not is falling foul of the etymological fallacy. Just like refusing to call a 'hamburger' or a 'hot dog' by their usual names.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is predicated on a misconception.

Comment: They are called silent films because the people are silent... their mouths move but there is no sound coming out. A film that is actually totally silent would be really dull to watch.

Comment: Wikipedia link [**During silent films, a pianist, theatre organist, or in large cities, even a small orchestra would often play music to accompany the films**. Pianists and organists would either play from sheet music or improvise; an orchestra would play from sheet music. The term *silent film* is therefore a **retronym** — that is, a term created to distinguish something retroactively.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_film) That is to say before sound was introduced, (silent) movies were called *motion pictures* or just *films*.

Comment: [Because of the limits of technology, films of the 1890s were under a minute long and **until 1927 motion pictures were produced without sound**. The first decade of *motion picture* saw *film* moving from a novelty to an established large-scale entertainment industry.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_film)

Comment: Although you're question will porbalby be closed, if you want to distinguish totally silent film from one with no human voice you could calque the name from French : "film muet" ="mute film"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"silent movies" or "silent films" are misnomers.**

Yes, most of them were not silent at all as they were provided with musical background and a few sound effects. However, "silent movies" or "silent films" is how they became known and all we can say is that these terms are [**"misnomers"**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misnomer).

> - An error in naming a person or place.

Examples of misnomers:

- "dial" or "redial" - we hardly find any rotatory phone these days.
- "catgut" - not made from cat's gut.
- "starfish" are not fish.
- etc.

**The correct name for a thing, however, is the name we call it, be it a misnomer or not.** But if you ask me what more descriptive term might have been coined for "silent movies", I would suggest [**"films without synchronized sound"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_film)

Comment: so what is the correct name of the Silent movies?

Comment: I like your explanation of how "silent film" is a misnomer. I'm not sure the question is salvageable, though, since it seems to mainly be a misguided request for new terminology for something that already has a name, with no clear criteria for selecting the best answer (the "correct" name).